# In Site.com, can I create expressions based on a value in a Data Repeater?

Tags: site.com, data-repeater

I know how to output values in Data Repeaters and how to do Data Functions, but I’m looking for a little more sophisticated logic than just outputting {!URL_state__c}. I imagine this must be doable, I just haven't figured it out yet.

I want to display content in a site.com page based on the logic of a field in a connected record. For instance, say there’s a field {!URL_state__c} on each record that will either be “CA” or “NV”, and based on that value I want the output on the site.com page to display a different link. If the value is “CA,” for example, I want the link to go the California URL and the text under it to be California-specific, and if it’s “NV,” a Nevada URL, with Nevada text. Any idea how to do this? Something like pseudocode {!IF(URL_state__c == 'CA'} ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer unfortunately is that this functionality is not yet supported in Site.com. You cannot perform expressions logic in Site.com.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using CSS and Javascript. I print all fields using data repeaters and hide/show based on the logic in custom JS files. Each field should have it's own unique class name (class attribute).